# Реализация cкандинавского аукциона на php, jqeury и ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Все привет. Понадобилось реализовать [аналог сайта-аукциона с оплатой за каждую ставку](https://bonusmall.ru/) В связи с этим возникли пару вопросов.

1. НА сайте примеры каждую секунду идет запрос на сервер. На сколько правильно это реализация?
2. Если это нормально не будет ли у меня слетать обновление БД, если допустим каждую секунду будут обновляться цены.
3. Все товары хранятся в БД. Скорей всего есть таблица - аукцион, где есть связь с таблицей товаров. Получается что при каждом обновлении цены, цена меняется и в таблице?
4. Если все выше перечисленное не верно, то как лучше реализовать сайт - аукцион, при условии что цена будет меняться каждую секунду.
5. На сайте примере я так понял, каждую секунду собирается все ставки, запихивают все в один ajax запрос json, и отправляют на обновление информации в БД.

Что скажете?

Comment: Слишком размытый вопрос. "Правильно" у каждого своё. Программа может быть сделана "правильно" с точки зрения "красоты кода" - тут представьте сколько вариантов. Программа может быть сделана "правильно" с точки зрения оптимального использования процессора, оптимального использования жесткого диска, оптимального использования памяти. Причем в даже в этих вариантах тоже есть еще частные случаи. Конкретизируйте свои задачи немного - вот частотой изменения таблицы Вы уже ужаснули нас. Давайте дальше)

Comment: Цены должны обновляться по крону в БД, а по ajax'у на сайте, и то, если цена обновилась. Представьте, если у Вас будет несколько тысяч лотов?

Comment: Незачем слать сегодня запросы каждую секунду, когда из JavaScript  можно установить постоянное соединение с сервером.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Каждую секунду отправляется ajax запрос при 10 000 пользователей?

   - это же DDOS атака. Это 10 000 отдельно работающих скриптов с 10 000 подключениями к базе данных
2. Как вы себе представляете ситуацию, если даже 5 000 пользователей
   одновременно сделают ставку на 1 товар? - должна быть очередность
3. 5 000 изменений в секунду записанной переменной на жесткий диск -
   как это реализуемо?
4. С трудом представляется реализация подобным образом .

На мой взгляд
    (имея опыт работы с вебсокетами, но не с Демонами PHP ) как
    реализовать:

На сервере постоянно работает вебсокет сервер. Каждым циклом он проходится по всем активным соединениям и проверяет поступило ли сообщение(обычно в зашифрованном виде +временная метка).По этой временной метке он узнает сколько изменений произошло, для того чтобы понимать по скольким позициям передавать информацию об изменениях, если пришла информация от клиента, проверяем ее и заносим ее в нашу переменную, находящуюся в оперативной памяти.

На клиентской стороне тикают таймеры сами по себе. Как только приходят новые данные с сервера в соответствии со скриптом данные обновляются, в том числе и конкретные таймеры.

Вебсокет сервер также следит за появлением новых товаров, участвующих в торгах и сообщает это клиентам. После того как аукцион состоялся - данные записываются в базу данных.

Если на стороне клиента связь оборвалась - браузер клиента пытается восстановить связь повторными обращениями к серверу. Сервер в свою очередь активно и периодически проверяет активность всех соединений, если какое-то соединение перестает отвечать, он его отключает для экономии пропускного канала.

"Представьте, если у Вас будет несколько тысяч лотов" - если вы говорите что у вас будет несколько тысяч активных лотов, это все равно что сказать, что у вас будут несколько десятков серверов. А если не активных - то их может быть сколько угодно.

Для того чтобы иметь понимание о стабильности Вебсокет сервера - надо собрать больше данных. Я же сделал такую схему - если клиент не может соединиться - он запускает вебсервер своим запросом.

Главный принцип скорости в таких проектах - держать быстро меняющуюся информацию в оперативной памяти. Между итерациями вебсокет сервера я поставил `usleep`

Будут вопросы - пишите - дополню ответ. По поводу высокой нагрузки - это уже технический вопрос по ее распределению между машинами и отдельная тема

Comment: Вы описываете ситуации, которые в реальности не будут существовать для стартапчика.

Comment: @Mcile спасибо за ответ. А вы смотрел аналог сайта в вопросе? там как раз такие реализовано так как я говорил? или я что то не так понял. И как сказал Гончаров Александр стартап дейстивительно не реализует такое.

Comment: Аналог смотрел. Что бы проверить как работает - необходимо запустить 3 окна в режиме инкогнито и практически одновременно выставить ставку. Наблюдатель должен заметить изменение по каждому из участников. Если наблюдатели увидят только конечного аукционера в периоде секунда и меньше(между ставками) - то да эта система вероятно опрашивает каждую секунду(хотя с трудом верится). Если наблюдатели увидят все изменения - то реализовано по технологии описанной выше. Если наблюдатели не увидят изменений, а только тот кто сделал ставку - то это развод.

Comment: @Mcile я просто открыл страницу, открыл просмотреть код - вкладка network И увидел как там каждую секунду отрабатывается файл ajax.php (смотрел на браузере google chrome)

Comment: @Mcile если что можно поработать над этим проектом вместе, напишите в skype обговорим условия duddeniska1

Answer (score 0):

Скандинавские аукционы находятся на грани мошенничества и торговли. На сайте-примере явно пишут что этот "аукцион" в кавычках - название акции. Моя вера в людей позволяет утверждать что такой сайт никогда не достигнет цели 10000 одновременных пользователей.

Если даже представить что он достигнет такой популярности, то в 2017 году даже 10000 пользователей не проблема, если продуманно кешировать данные. Может быть вам понадобится больше чем один сервер, но и то схема будет очень проста.

Прелесть скандинавского аукциона, которая приводит к технической простоте реализации, заключается в следующем: цена всегда повышается на фиксированную величину, равную размеру ставки. Значит вы можете обновлять цену по каждому лоту одним запросом, без транзакций:

```
UPDATE items SET price = price + 10 WHERE id = 123546;
```

То же относится к времени окончания аукциона. Лидер аукциона устанавливается простым `INSERT` в таблицу ставок: этот запрос стоит делать до установки цены. Все очень просто.

Дальше вы можете либо получать данные напрямую из БД, либо после ставки класть данные по этому лоту в кеш. Либо можно сохранять уже готовый ответ по этому аукциону прямо в файл на диске. Надо ли говорить что для nginx вообще нет никакой проблемы раздавать тысячи JSON файлов.